# Matrix Row - QuickSort recursion problem

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, algorithm, recursion

I've adapted QuickSort Method to sort Array's Row.
Here's the code:

That one works fine

```
static void QuickSort(int lowBound, int highBound, int[] a)
        {
            int temp = 0;
            int x = random.Next(lowBound, highBound);
            int pivot = a[x];
            int i = lowBound;
            int j = highBound;
            do 
            {
                while (a[i] < pivot) i++;
                while (pivot < a[j]) j--;
                if (i <= j)
                {
                    temp = a[i]; //changes an element smaller than the pivot...
                    a[i] = a[j];//... with the greater one
                    a[j] = temp;
                    i++; j--;
                }

            }
            while (i <= j);
            if (lowBound < j) { QuickSort(lowBound, j, a); }//recursion 
            if (i < highBound){ QuickSort(i,highBound, a); }
        }
```

Here's the problematic method

```
static void QuickSortMatrix(int[,] a)
        {
            int n = a.GetLength(0);
            int m = a.GetLength(1);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                QuickSortRow(0, m - 1, i, a);
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                QuickSortRow(0, n - 1, j, a);
            }

        }
        static void QuickSortRow(int lowBound, int highBound, int row, int[,] a)
        {
            int temp = 0;            
            int x = random.Next(lowBound, highBound);
            int pivot = a[row,x];
            int p = lowBound;
            int q = highBound;
            do 
            {
                while (a[row,p] < pivot) p++;
                while (pivot < a[row,q]) q--;
                if (p <= q)
                {
                    temp = a[row,p];
                    a[row,p] = a[row,q];
                    a[row,q] = temp;
                    p++; q--;
                }

            }
            while (p <= q);
            if (lowBound < q)  { QuickSortRow(lowBound, q, row, a); }
            if (p < highBound) { QuickSortRow(p, highBound,row, a); }
        }
```

At first when the "for" loop is executed everything's ok bur for some reason when executed recursively the row that should be constant when calling the method goes outside the matrix boundaries.
Here's my array and rows reaches value of 4

```
int[,] matrix = 
                {
                    {7,8,9,10,11,5},
                    {3,6,4,16,22,4},
                    {7,9,17,8,3,21},
                    {24,7,11,19,3,4}
                };
```

I hope my explanation was clear enough.

Could anybody advise me? What I'm missing here?

Thank you for your kind help!

BR
Stephan

Comment: For one, variable names with more than 1 character are useful. This is hard to read

Comment: It's impossible to read.  Why use 'q' instead of 'highBound'?  The first isn't descriptive at all while the second tells me what that variable does at a glance.  Instead of 'q', why not use 'highBoundTmp', or 'currentHighBound' or something?

Comment: Thank u guys I'll bear that in mind in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

n is the number of rows in the matrix (4)

m is the number of columns in the matrix (6)

In your second loop you are going 0..m and passing that value to the row parameter. It blows up because there are more columns in the matrix than rows. i.e. It tries to read matrix[4, 0].

Note: as far as I can tell you don't need the second loop because your rows are already sorted after the first loop. Remove that and it won't throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you, I'm calling the wrong method in the second loop, didn't saw that and of course I go out of boundaries!